# Is discontinuity along a line equivalent to branch cut?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, analyticity, branch-cuts

Suppose I claim the analytic function $f(z)$ has a branch cut along the positive real line, how would one go on to prove this?

Is it sufficient to prove that $f(z)$ is discontinuous across this line?

Thanks

Comment: If $f$ is a multiple-valued function, but can properly be defined as an analytic function in the remaining part of the plane, then the positive real line is a branch cut of $f$ (but I know of no context where it could be considered as 'the' branch-cut, so that you could say that $f$ has a branch-cut there--and nowhere else).

Comment: OK let me put it like this: By definition $f$ is an analytic function on C, except having a line of discontinuity along positive R. Can we call this line a branch cut for $f$?

Comment: The term branch-cut is used for 'formalizing' the graph of a multiple-valued function as the 'glued-together' graphs of proper analytic functions. To the best of my knowledge, there's no reason or a formally-pleasing way of getting to it from the other direction.

Comment: So to clarify, maybe you are asking: Can such an $f$ (which cannot be analytically continued across any portion of the positive real cut) only come from a branch of a multivalued function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related result: Using [Morera's theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_Theorem) if $f$ is continuous across some portion of the cut, then it can be made analytic across the cut, and thus $f$ can be extended across this portion of the cut. So, I suppose that if $f$ is not continuous across any portion of the cut, then the cut behaves like a branch cut... I'm not sure I would call it a branch cut though, as Jonathan points out, there is a specific meaning for that.

Still interesting, I suppose another question could be, is there always a Riemann surface for which $f$ can be continued analytically?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on exactly what you mean by *branch cut*, but I would interpret it in the way @Evan does: that $f$ can be extended to some Riemann surface. In that case, the answer is no. Being discontinuous along the line is not enough. In fact, the function at least has to be continuous from both sides, but even that isn't enough.

A fairly simple example is to construct a holomorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus L$ with zeros accumulating along one (or both) sides of $L$. By the identity theorem, this $f$ can't be extended across $L$, so there is no hope of a Riemann surface extension.